# segmentation fault in reading /proc/pid/maps

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read `maps` line by line, but I get the error core `segmentation fault` error... Can anyone give me some advice on my code? I'm using `3.13.0-32-generic`

```
int main()
{
    char buf[512];
    FILE *f;
    sprintf(buf, "/proc/%d/maps", getpid());
    f = fopen(buf, "rt");
    while (fgets(buf, 512, f)) {
        unsigned int from, to, pgoff, major, minor;
        unsigned long ino;
        char flags[4];
        int ret = sscanf(buf, "%x-%x %c%c%c%c %x %x:%x %lu ", &from, &to, flags[0],flags[1],flags[2],flags[3], &pgoff, &major, &minor,ino);
            if (ret != 10)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have gotten warnings, and you could have debugged yourself.

Comment: Who voted to close this? The question contains an error description and a minimal self-contained example, what else do you require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass pointers to the members of the `flags` array instead of passing them directly, the same applies to the `ino` argument:

```
sscanf(buf, "%x-%x %c%c%c%c %x %x:%x %lu ", &from, &to,
    &flags[0], &flags[1], &flags[2], &flags[3],
    &pgoff, &major, &minor, &ino);
```

Alternatively, scan all characters at once:

```
sscanf(buf, "%x-%x %4c %x %x:%x %lu ", &from, &to,
    flags, &pgoff, &major, &minor, &ino);
```

Notice the missing `&` before `flags` as the array is automatically converted into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I have corrected this problem, but the error remains....

Comment: I think the same goes for `ino`

Answer (score 1):

In the scanf call replace

```
flags[x]
```

by

```
&flags[x]
```

same goes for `ino`.